# Supervisor not loading new configuration files

Tags: deployment, supervisord, gunicorn

I have a problem deploying Django app using Gunicorn and Supervisor. While I can make Gunicorn serving my app (by setting proper PYTHONPATH and running apropriate command, the one from supervisord config) I can't make supervisor to run it. It just won't see my app. I don't know how to make sure if the config file is ok.

Here's what supervisorctl says:

```
# supervisorctl start myapp_live
myapp_live: ERROR (no such process)
```

I'm running it on Ubuntu 10.04 with following config:

File /home/myapp/live/deploy/supervisord_live.ini:

```
[program:myapp_live]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn_django --log-file /home/myapp/logs/gunicorn_live.log --log-level info --workers 2 -t 120 -b 127.0.0.1:10000 -p deploy/gunicorn_live.pid webapp/settings_live.py
directory=/home/myapp/live
environment=PYTHONPATH='/home/myapp/live/eco/lib'
user=myapp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

In /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf, at the end of the file, there is:

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

and here's a symlink to my config file:

```
# ls -la /etc/supervisor/conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48 Dec  4 18:02 myapp-live.conf -> /home/myapp/live/deploy/supervisord_live.ini
```

everything looks fine for me but supervisorctl just keep saying `myapp_live: ERROR (no such process)`. Any solution for this?

Comment: I was scratching my head with the same problem; my configuration files weren't being loaded when I ran `reread` or `update`. It turned out I had saved my config files as `foo.conf.py` instead of `foo.conf` so they weren't being identified.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had the same issue, a

```
sudo service supervisord reload
```

did the trick, though I don't know if that is the answer to your question.

Comment: I stopped and then started supervisor some time ago and it worked. Don't know if reload would work (as I heart restart doesn't) but I guess it could

Comment: I did it too and it got worked.  I wonder why `/etc/init.d/supervisor restart` doesn't work when manual stop and start do.

Comment: Worked for me, though the service didn't work so I just ran `ps aux | grep supervisor` and then `sudo kill -HUP pid`

Comment: This is dangerous as it will restart the whole of the supervisor daemon.

Comment: supervisorctl reread can fix this aswell without restarting the service.

Comment: On ubuntu 12.04 commands ```service supervisor stop``` and then ```service supervisor start``` fix this issuee

Comment: Be careful! reload will restart all services in all configurations...

Comment: I tried to stop and restart, but this `reload` is the one that worked. thank you!

Answer (score 281):

The correct answer is that supervisor requires you to re-read *and* update when you place a new configuration file. Restarting is not the answer, as that will affect other services. Try:

```
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  "supervisor reread" alone is not enough.

Comment: +1 This is a better answer because it doesn't rely on Process Managers.

Comment: "supervisorctl reread" alone is not enough, but wouldn't "supervisorctl update" suffice? According to the documentation "update" does a reread followed by a restart of any programs whose configuration was modified by the reread.

Comment: It work for me. I have done restart afterward.

Comment: @BlueBomber Yes, but reread will tell you what's changed *first* so you don't accidentally reload something else unintentionally.

Comment: Will this also work if I changed something in `[inet_http_server]`?

Answer (score 26):

Make sure your supervisor conf files end in .conf

Took me a while to figure that one out. Hopefully it helps the next person.

Comment: Wasted an hour on the same issue - can't believe it was this simple.

Comment: Thanks for listing this answer. For the life of me, I could not figure this one out.

Comment: Lol, I've named my config file <my-config>.py. I'm tired :D Thanks !

Comment: Amazing response.

Answer (score 15):

Reloading the master supervisor process may work, but it will have unintended side effects if you have more than one process being monitored by supervisor.

The correct way to do it is to issue `supervisorctl reread` which causes it to scan configuration files for any changes:

```
root@debian:~# supervisorctl reread
gunicorn: changed
```

Then, simply reload that app:

```
root@debian:~# supervisorctl restart gunicorn
gunicorn: stopped
gunicorn: started
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you only want to read a changed/new config file and leave the rest of the running processes untouched. Supervisorctl will show the new app is `avail`. Add it to the (re)startable processes by issueing `supervisorctl update`. See also Mark's answer http://serverfault.com/a/479754/125887

Comment: This was not enough for me. `supervisorctl update` was necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem ( `myapp_live: ERROR (no such process)` ) and it was because my process definition was

```
[program: myapp_live]
```

when it should have been

```
[program:myapp_live]
```

While this doesn't address the question that was asked, I was lead here by the Search that Be looking for a solution to my problem, so hopefully other people find it here, too.

Comment: Same here! I had left it as `[program]` only, following the docs, but making it `[program:redis]` made it work for me. Things sure get weird at times!

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem using the supervisor package, version 3.0a8-1.1 from Ubuntu Server 12.10.  I ended up solving the problem by reading the built-in help:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl help restart
restart <name>          Restart a process
restart <gname>:*       Restart all processes in a group
restart <name> <name>   Restart multiple processes or groups
restart all             Restart all processes
```

In particular you want to use the  syntax:

```
sudo supervisorctl restart myapp_live:*
```

As the documentation states at http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#programx-section -- "A [program:x] section actually represents a “homogeneous process group” to supervisor (as of 3.0)."  So maybe the problem first surfaced in version 3.0.

PS:  I'm new to supervisor; I'm using https://github.com/bdarnell/tornado-production-skeleton/blob/8ad055457646929c0e8f48aaf20d98f054b1787b/production/chat.supervisor as an example of what a minimal configuration should look like.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a checklist:

1. The new config file should be named according to the include pattern configured in /etc/supervisord.conf:

   ```
   [include]
   files=supervisord.d/*.ini
   ```

   As we see in my case, spam.ini would be included, but spam.conf would not.
2. If you created the new file by copying an old one, make sure to actually change the `[program:]` line. Otherwise, `supervisorctl reread` will not tell you so:

   ```
   No config updates to processes
   ```
3. If your file is detected, `supervisorctl reread` should say something like:

   ```
   spam: available
   ```
4. Then, `supervisorctl update spam` should both start it and make it appear in `supervisorctl status`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the init.d scripts to be unreliable on a variety of different Ubuntu/Debian versions. The way to do it is this:

```
sudo supervisorctl reload
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do it although it will work in many circumstances. @burhan-khalid answer is the right one, and provides an explanation for it.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution to be most convenient:

EDIT: before doing this check your supervisorctl path using `which supervisorctl` to make sure you are adding right path to sudoers.

Add this line to sudoers file using `visudo` (where: `myappuser` - the user that needs to restart your app, `myapp` - app name):

```
myappuser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart myapp
```

And then simply:

```
sudo supervisorctl restart myapp
```

You are not tied to distribution's startup scripts and you give quite narrow privileges to user restarting your gunicorn app. Also, you don't need to care about pid. The command will not ask for password so it's suitable for auto-deployment bash/fabric scripts. On the other hand - you have to be aware, that if supervisorctl is vulnerable to some bug causing code execution a malicious user could use this sudo privilege to run code as root (but as far as I know no such bug was discovered for supervisord and it's a big thing to find such vulnerability).

Answer (score 2):

Reading the code of supervisorctl.py here:
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/supervisorctl.py

You can see that supervisorctl update (function do_update) is calling reloadConfig() exactly as supervisorctl reread (function do_reread) does.

So i think that calling reread is not necessary if you call update after it.

From the output of git blame it has been like this since at least since july 2009.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed supervisrod with yum install, which installed supervisor of version v2.*. Supervisor supports external includes only from version 3. Had to use easy_install instead, to install supervisor v3.

Comment: This was also my issue, it will probably occur on all Centos 6.5 or less installs.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with symlinks and include files on Supervisor.

It would allow any person with w privilege on `/home/myapp/live/deploy/supervisord_live.ini` to change the `ini` file and start any malicious code.

This `ini` file should be inside your supervisor's conf directory or in any sub dir under it.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing I had to do is change the file permissions of the script by running the following command:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/your_script
```

This [digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) can be of great help to help you figure out some issues.