# Strange behavior with supervisor, gunicorn and Django

Tags: django, environment-variables, supervisord, gunicorn

I have a really strange problem with supervisor and gunicorn.
I read supervisor [documentation](http://supervisord.org/index.html), all the relevant blog posts, [stackexchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/211525/supervisor-not-loading-new-configuration-files) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293801/supervisor-not-working-with-gunicorn-flask) but none of them solve my strange problem, and I don't even know where to look further.

My supervisor configuration:

```
[program:djangoapp]
user = regularuser
directory = /path/to/djangoapp
command =
        /path/to/djangoapp/.venv/bin/gunicorn
        --debug
        --log-file -
        --log-level debug
        --name arlista
        --workers 9
        --pythonpath /path/to/necessary/library/source/Python
        djangoapp.wsgi:application
stdout_logfile = /path/to/logfolder/djangoapp.log
autorestart = true
redirect_stderr = true
environment =
        GPG_PASSPHRASE="a_passhprase_with_a_comma_in_it",
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings.production",
        DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="secret_key_working_fine",
        DJANGO_DB_ENGINE="django.db.backends.mysql",
        DJANGO_DB_HOST="localhost",
        DJANGO_DB_NAME="dbname",
        DJANGO_DB_USER="dbuser",
        DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD="dbpassword",
        DJANGO_MEDIA_ROOT="/path/to/djangoapp/media",
        DJANGO_STATIC_ROOT="/path/to/djangoapp/static_root",
        # a couple more environment variables here for Django
```

Everything seems to work fine. It can connect to the database, I can see the `djangoapp.log`, the `myapp.settings.production` file's pyc is generated so settings are loaded. `DJANGO_MEDIA_ROOT` works fine, because images are served from that folder (and if I remove that setting, Django don't even start).

**HOWEVER** there are pages, when encrypted images got decrypted on the fly (that's why GPG_PASSHPRASE is necessary) and those give me blank images (images with zero length, so Django works, but the decryption does not). The decryption is made by `/usr/bin/gpg`. The function which handles the decryption is in a package in `/path/to/necessary/library/source/Python`. `regularuser` can read packages from that folder.

If I run the process with upstart, passing in the same environment variables with `env` stanza or even reading them from file, everything is fine, images got decrypted, but not with supervisor.

I tried environment variables with single quote, no quote, pass `PYTHONPATH` to gunicorn `--pythonpath` or the environment option, and have still no luck. What can I do? Can it be a problem that GPG_PASSHPRASE contains a comma? (I can't change that.) What else? I really run out of ideas.

Comment: What version of supervisor are you using ? I have 3.0b2 and a made a little test where I can successfully set an env variable with a comma in it

Comment: 3.1.2, so that can't be a problem hopefully :)

Comment: I have noticed that supervisor suppress Django environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably can't help, but I'l throw out some possibilities (which might be totally wrong)

- No whitespace before last line of command ("`djangoapp...`"). Possible that some step in your buildchain is concatenating this with the previous `--pythonpath` flag, and both are being ignored.
- Comma in passcode (doubtful) -- Have you tried just changing the passcode? Or escaping the comma?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. There were tabulator characters in the file and no other whitespace between the environment lines. I converted every tab to space and everything seems to be working fine! Thanks!

Comment: maybe not, because I rewrote tabs and working fine...